# Which translation is the most accurate for the phrase "העוֹנה לתפלת חסיד ידשׁן בּטוֹב חיינוּ ושׁנה טוֹבה ישׁלח לבית ישׂראל עמנוּ"?

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, translation, rosh-hashanah-new-year

My suggestions:

העוֹנה לתפלת חסיד

- The response/answer to the prayer of a righteous person
- The return to prayer of a righteous person
- The season of prayer of a righteous person

ידשׁן בּטוֹב חיינוּ

- is a good thing in our lives
- is the goodness in our lives
- is the best in our lives

ושׁנה טוֹבה ישׁלח

- and He will send a good year

לבית ישׂראל עמנוּ

- to our people, the House of Israel.

Comment: Where did you find this phrase?

Comment: I found this phrase on a greeting card.

Answer (score 2):

העוֹנה לתפלת חסיד

[The One] who answers the prayers of the pious

ידשׁן בּטוֹב חיינוּ

[Pray, may He] improve our lives with goodness

ושׁנה טוֹבה ישׁלח

and send a good year

לבית ישׂראל עמנוּ

to our people, the House of Israel.